# Redux state is being mutated with lodash's mergeWith

Tags: javascript, redux, lodash

I am using lodash's `mergeWith` to merge some payload data into some of my redux state. However, when doing this, I end up directly mutating state. I don't understand how this is happening, since I am using `{...state}` to make the merge occur. Why is this happening and what can I do to not mutate my state directly? You can see the below snippet for an example of what is happening. Thanks!

```js
const merger = (objectOne, objectTwo) => {
  const customizer = (firstValue, secondValue) => {
    return _.isArray(firstValue) ? secondValue : undefined;
  };

  return _.mergeWith(objectOne, objectTwo, customizer);
};

const state = {
  1: {a: true, b: true, c: true},
  2: {a: true, b: true, c: true},
  3: {a: true, b: true, c: true},
}

const payload = {
   2: {a: true, b: false, c: true},
}

console.log("Merged data:");
console.log(merger({...state}, payload));
console.log("Manipulated state:");
console.log(state);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is in a nut shell the issue:

```js
let a = { foo: 'A'}
let c = { ... a }  // shallow copy of a

a.foo = 'boo'

console.log(a)
console.log(c) // works as expected c.foo is NOT changed and still is 'A'
```

As you can see from the above example with spreading and value based properties shallow copy works as expected. However when you do this:

```js
let x = { foo: { boo: 'A' }}  // object as value this time
let y = { ... x }  // shallow copy of x

x.foo.boo = 'beer'

console.log(x.foo.boo)
console.log(y.foo.boo) // should be 'boo' but it is 'beer'
```

Shallow copy does not work as well since the `clone` has references pointing to the old `x` objects instead of cloned ones.

To remedy this and also to to make your code somewhat more concise you could:

```js
const state = { 1: {a: true, b: true, c: true}, 2: {a: true, b: true, c: true}, 3: {a: true, b: true, c: true}, }
const payload = { 2: {a: true, b: false, c: true} }

const merger = (...args) => _.mergeWith(...args, (a,b) => _.isArray(a) ? b : undefined)

console.log("Merged data:");
console.log(merger(_.cloneDeep(state), payload));
console.log("Manipulated state:");
console.log(state);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

First switch ot lodash [`_.cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep) which would deep copy your entire object tree and also you can make your `merge` method more concise with ES6 `spread` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be aware that the spread syntax `{ ...state }` does only a shallow copy of your object. So in a fact - the deeply nested properties - in your particular case `{ a: true, b: true, c: true }` remain the same objects by reference. If you wish to avoid the state mutation error, you should use e.g. `cloneDeep` function from lodash.

`merger(_.cloneDeep(state), payload);`